# MP3 Frame Header Detection FFF/FFE sync issue

Tags: c++, c, header, mp3, frames

I am trying to parse a MP3 file and detect all frames in a Variable Bit Rate (VBR) MP3 file. I have looked all over the internet and could not find a proper solution to detect new frame header sync. From other posts it says I should look for FFE or FFF but in my program it will not detect it properly. I do not understand how am I supposed to look for FFF or FFE ? I get FFE as 0xF and next byte as 0xFE but how do get FFF I get the header from this to build the needed 11 bits of 1 ? 
I have looked over [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header) which is linked in all other topics and websites as the go to place for MP3 reference, and its source code but the part that covers my question is, I presume in the CMPA* files which are not given in the source code download.

```
do 
    {
        uiFrame = getc(pFile);
        if(EOF == uiFrame)
            break;
        cntSize++;
        if(0xFF == uiFrame)
        {
            uiFrame = getc(pFile);
            if(EOF == uiFrame)
                break;
            if((0xE == uiFrame) )//|| (0xE0 == uiFrame))
            {
                if(1 != uiFrameCount)
                    printf("\nFrame Size is %d \n\n",cntSize - PrevoiusFrameSize);

                printf("\nFrame Found at Byte %d", cntSize);
                PrevoiusFrameSize = cntSize;
                CheckFlag         = 1;
                uiFrameCount++;
            }
            cntSize++;
        }
    }while(1 != CheckFlag);
```

When I execute the code above or any variant of it that I can think of I obtain 1 to 6 frames whereas if I use the program itself from the link above it says 8855 frames on my test mp3 file. Any help on this matter would be GREATLY appreciated as I am running out of ideas and pages of google to look on for an answer.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
After swift reply from Marc B I mostly understood the issue but after editing to reflect his answer I am now detecting only 4 frames,up from one. 
Here is the code part that does the frame detection, am I doing something wrong ?

```
do 
    {
        uiFrame = getc(pFile);
        if(EOF == uiFrame)
            break;
        cntSize++;
        if(0xFF == uiFrame)
        {
            uiFrame = getc(pFile);
            if(EOF == uiFrame)
                break;
            uiShift=uiFrame>>4;
            if((0xE == uiShift) || (0xF == uiShift))
            {
                if(1 != uiFrameCount)
                    printf("\nFrame Size is %d \n\n",cntSize - PrevoiusFrameSize);

                printf("\nFrame Found at Byte %d", cntSize);
                PrevoiusFrameSize = cntSize;
                CheckFlag         = 1;
                uiFrameCount++;
            }
            cntSize++;
        }
    }while(1 != CheckFlag);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the frames are a fixed number of samples

Comment: I am concerned with DETECTING the frames in a VBR file where the frames are of Variable length so I cannot use a formula to calculate it, I need to parse the whole file to find the actual values, not aproximations.

Comment: i didn't say fixed number of bytes, I said samples. The frame size is a fixed number of samples (regardless of bit rate). [This](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) link may help (`ctrl + f` *frame size*). You can't parse/detect every byte in the file for a sync sequence, you'll inevitably run into sound-data that, coincidentally, contains the same sequence.

Comment: @TaylorFlores: technically, you do. mp3 frames can be embedded anywhere in a file. if you find one frame, the next frame is not necessarily immediately adjacent. while most files ARE pure mp3, mp3 was designed for embedding..  the data immediately after a frame might be something else, like mpeg video.

Comment: @MarcB interesting, didn't know that. I'm just trying to point out, though, that it looks like the code is parsing every single byte in the file for a sync sequence, without jumping over the frame data.

Comment: yeah. true. once you've identified a frame, the size of the frame can be easily calculated and skip the rest of the actual audio data. but once you've skipped, you have to start detecting frame headers again, because there's no guarantee you'll get another frame right away.

Comment: yeah I see what you mean know. I never did find out the rational of the sync sequence until now, makes sense. Are different codecs identified with difference sync sequences?

Answer (score 1):

The header's 3 nibbles (aka 1.5 bytes), so you need to do some bit shifting. in pseudo-code:

```
$data = 'FFEABCDEF....'
         ^^^--3 nibble header
$nibble1 = $data[0];
$nibble2 = $data[1] >> 4; // isolate 3rd nibble
if ($nibble1 == 'FF') && (($nibble2 == 'F') || ($nibble2 == 'E')) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, I will try it right away. Thanks for swift reply, I`ll be back with results hopefully.

Comment: One additional question, why is FFF a sync sequence ? It would be 12 bits and not 11 as I see in the specification ... please explain ?

Comment: it's been a long while since I dug into the mp3 specs, but I seem to remember they chose FFE as a value that would normally not appear within a frame. FFF requires 12 bytes to represent (11111111 + 1111), but FFE is only 11 (11111111 + 1110)

Comment: So if they chose FFE as a sequence why is FFF also looked after for sync ? It is 12 bits not 11.

Comment: I have added some edits to my code in original post, could you have a new look at it please if something else looks wrong in it to detect only 4 frames ?

Comment: problem is that mp3 frames are variable sized, depending on the sampling rate and frequency. Every frame is a constant playback-time in length (0.028 seconds? don't quote me on that, it's been a LONG time since I dealt with mp3 at this level). But a 44.1khz/16bit @ 256kbit frame is going to be much longer than a 11.05khz/8bit @ 48kbit frame. once you've got the frame header, you need to dig around in the frame and figure out its stats. from that you can calculate its byte size.

Comment: there's also no way to tell in advance if a particular mp3 tune is VBR or CBR, except by scanning the ENTIRE file and checking each frame's bit/sample rates. if they're constant through the file, then it's a CBR file. if a single frame has a different bit/sample rate, then it's VBR.

Comment: The first frame detected is at byte position 4097, I know mp3 files contents can be of variable length but is the first frame header to be found at this location a bad sign or nothing specific as there may be other information in before ?

Comment: there's ID3v2 records, which can be of any lenght stored at the start of the file. And ID3v1 which can be 128 bytes at the end of the file. The mp3 could also be embedded in somethign else, like a .wav file container. So it's absolutely normal to find the first frame "deep" inside the file, and not at byte 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to proceed frame by frame.
Each frame starts with a 32 bit header that you need to "decode".
Check the following [document](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)

Once done you'll have the offset to the next [header+frame] block.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily reverse the order of the bytes in the (4 byte) frame header with the followin C macro:

```
#define swaplong(x)  (unsigned  long)((((x)>>24) & 0xFF) |
((((x) & 0xFF0000) >> 8) & 0xFF00) | (((x) & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((x) << 24))
```

Then the syncrhonization bits are adjacent (again) and analysis is more straightforward.

Comment: I've put the code into a code block for you, so the initial `#` is back in; feel free to edit it further to add some indentation if it's required.